# Converting a complex T-SQL query that contains row_number partitioning, sum partitioning and a having clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

I had to take a different approach this the conversion I am working on from previous examples I posted on this site.

The following is a simple dataset I am using in order to try to conver my T-SQL to Linq in my C# application:

```
create table #sampledata 
(
    name nvarchar(50),
    sampletime datetime,
    samplevalue decimal, 
);

insert into #sampledata (name, sampletime, samplevalue) values
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:05:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:10:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:15:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:20:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:25:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:30:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:50:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:55:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:05:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:10:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:15:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:20:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:25:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:30:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:50:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:55:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:00:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:05:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:10:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:15:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:20:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:25:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:30:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:05:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:10:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:15:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:20:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:25:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:30:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:50:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:55:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:05:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:10:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:15:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:20:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:25:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:30:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:50:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:55:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:00:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:05:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:10:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:15:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:20:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:25:00 PM' as datetime), 40.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:30:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00)
```

As a result I want to group each name and nulls and find the minimum and maximum times the nulls occur, and clean up any noise.

I found an optimal way to achieve this in T-SQL. But before we get there take note that the rows have a 5 minute interval and for this example I only want to determine date ranges for names that are greater han 10 minutes.

My query will make what I want to achieve more clear:

```
declare @sampletime_interval int = 5
declare @noise_interval int = 10

;with a as
(
    select 
        name,
        sampletime,
        samplevalue,
        row_number() over (partition by name order by name, sampletime)    as rownum
    from #sampledata where samplevalue is null
)
select 
    b.name,
    min(b.sampletime) as startdate,
    max(b.sampletime) as enddate    
from
(
    select 
        a.name,
        a.sampletime,
        sum(case when datediff(minute, a1.sampletime, a.sampletime) >     @sampletime_interval then 1 else 0 end)    
        over (partition by a.name order by a.name, a.sampletime) as block
    from a left join a as a1 on a.name = a1.name and a.rownum =     a1.rownum + 1
) as b group by b.name, b.block 
having datediff(minute, min(b.sampletime), max(b.sampletime)) >=     @noise_interval
order by b.name, min(b.sampletime)
```

This is what I have so far using LINQ, it is not much, but I am not sure how to do:

```
sum(case when datediff(minute, a1.sampletime, a.sampletime) > @sampletime_interval then 1 else 0 end)    
    over (partition by a.name order by a.name, a.sampletime) as block

having datediff(minute, min(b.sampletime), max(b.sampletime)) >=    @noise_interval
```

LINQ C#:

```
// Fetch the data with samplevalue as null and put in memory.
var q1 = (from s in sampledata where samplevalue == null).ToList();

// Apply the row_number() over (partition by name order by name, sampletime)
var q2 = q1.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .ThenBy(x => x.SampleTime)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new { Group = g, Count = g.Count() })
    .SelectMany(g => g.Group.Select(b => b)
    .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, g.Count), (j, i) =>
    new 
    {
        Name = j.Name,
        SampleTime = j.SampleTime,
        SampleValue = j.SampleValue,
        RowNum = i
    }));
```

But I am not sure where to go from here. I looked at partition operators here, but not clear how to apply them for my case.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Partitioning-Operators-c68aaccc

The expected output for the T-SQL (using SQL Server 2012) should be:

[image]

Comment: Please post expected output as well

Comment: Why not create a function in T-SQL and then simply execute function in T-SQL.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, Unfortunately for this exercise that is not possible. We prefer to see if we can re-create this using LINQ in a web service. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I made an error in my t-sql query. And it effected my final output. I've made the appropriate changes above